# Can't get permission for deleting a file - not even as root!

Tags: permissions

I understand similar questions have been asked but truthfully none answer my question.

I downloaded a file using a torrent, and basically I need to replace a .jar file in there with another, yet NOTHING I do will give me permission to do so!

```
~/virtual-drives/1/java/jar$ rm install.jar
rm: cannot remove ‘install.jar’: Function not implemented
```

so when I go through sudo:

```
~/virtual-drives/1/java/jar$ sudo rm install.jar
rm: cannot remove ‘install.jar’: Permission denied
```

and as root:

```
 /home/joshuajoseph/virtual-drives/1/java/jar# rm install.jar
 rm: cannot remove ‘install.jar’: Permission denied
```

can't even change permissions:

```
/home/joshuajoseph/virtual-drives/1/java/jar# chmod 777 /home/joshuajoseph/virtual-drives/1/java/jar/
chmod: cannot access ‘/home/joshuajoseph/virtual-drives/1/java/jar/’: Permission denied
```

I can't even do it when I go manually through the archive manager, that still doesn't allow me to delete it.

so as you see, NOTHING I do is working. Can anyone offer a suggestion? I welcome them all!

Comment: Look at this:  (http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/7468) According to this, file is part of folder, so you also must check if you have permissions for that folder, including group permission.

Comment: @Xieerqi root always has permissions. Joshua, this virtual drive, is it a separate partition? Is it mounted read-only?

Comment: @muru It is mounted but this seems to suggest it is read-write: fuseiso on /home/joshuajoseph/virtual-drives/1 type fuse.fuseiso (rw,nosuid,nodev,user=joshuajoseph) yeah I understand root should be able to do all, perhaps I'm not entering the right commands?

Comment: @muru Also I thought I'd show this, when I ls -l in the virtual drives directory, I see 7 directories there. Only directory 1 is mounted right now, and when I'm root attempting to change permissions, this is what I see. The remaining 3 - 7 look the same as number 2: d????????? ? ? ? ? ? 1 | drwxrwxrwx 2 joshuajoseph joshuajoseph 4096 Sep 21 01:12 2

Comment: @muru sorry for the amount of comments, just trying to give as much info as possible. When I'm in virtual drive 1, the mounted one, and I ls inside there as root, here's what I get: root@joshuajoseph-HP-Compaq-6710b:/home/joshuajoseph/virtual-drives/1# ls
ls: cannot open directory .: Permission denied
See what I mean? As root I'm not allowed any permissions? What's going on here?

Comment: @JoshuaD'Agostino it's preferred that you edit the question the add more information. It's hard to read output in comments.

Comment: @muru okay sorry. Basically what I have tried to say above: user can see permissions and details of virtual drives, root can't, nor can root see the contents of the virtual drive. This is undoubtedly part of the problem but I have no idea how to fix this considering root should be always able to have permission.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `fuse` to mount the images. From [`man mount.fuse`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man8/mount.fuse.8.html#contenttoc5) (section on SECURITY):

```
3. No other user (including root) can access the contents of the mounted filesystem.
```

Even though the mount options say `rw`, I think you cannot use it to modify ISOs. You'll have to use other tools like 
[isomaster](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/saucy/isomaster/) for that.

Comment: Ah alright I see, is there a way around this then?

Comment: @JoshuaD'Agostino even though it says its mounted `rw`, I don't think you can delete/modify files in ISOs via fuse. I think you should look at some iso editing tool.

Comment: Cheers, used ISO Master. Works a charm. Thanks for your help!